# How to list files in selected internal directories

Tags: bash, unix, ls

How do I list all jars as target/scala*jar , where target might at any level relative to my current directory.
eg

```
curr_dir-
        |-target/scalaasd.jar
        |-shell/scala2.jar
        `-dir1/dir2/dir3/target/scala3.jar
```

The command should output first and third jars.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./$(find . -type d -iname target) -type f -iname "scala*.jar" -maxdepth 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
printf '%s\n' **/target/scala*jar
```

When `globstar` is enabled the pattern `**` can match multiple directory levels.  See the Bash manual page for more information.